# Contar palabras que son iguales que la primera palabra de un Vector

Tags: pseudocódigo

me gustaría saber cómo hacer éste ejercicio:

Dada una frase acabada en punto en un vector, realiza un algoritmo que nos diga cuántas palabras son iguales que la primera palabra.

No necesito el código, ya que lo estamos haciendo en pseudocódigo, pero haremos C dentro de nada.

El caso es que yo he leído el vector introducido por el usuario, luego he leído la primera palabra y la he guardado en un vector "j". Después he leído palabra por palabra del vector para ir comparando: si `v[i] == j[i]` (primera palabra), entonces, que `cont = cont +1`.

El problema es que no sé cómo hacer para " ir cogiendo" palabra a palabra para ir comparándolo.

He hecho este bucle:

```
i = 0;

mientras (i < = 20) & (v[i] != '.') & (v[i] != ' ') hacer

    si (v[i] == j[i]) entonces
       cont = cont +1;
    fsi
    i ++;
fmientras
```

No sé si está bien lo que he hecho, pero bueno.

Comment: Llevas algo intentado en el lenguaje C?

Comment: Sí, pero no mucho, más que nada por mi cuenta.
Pero no hay mucha diferencia entre pseudocódigo y C.

Un saludo y gracias por responder.

Comment: Entonces edita tu respuesta agregando el código C que has intentado :), porque, como comprenderas, no puedo compilar pseudocódigo :(

Comment: Pero yo no lo he hecho en C, lo he hecho en pseudocódigo, solo necesito saber cómo se hace, es decir, el razonamiento.

Comment: Entonces la etiqueta correcta no sería C, sino [tag:pseudocodigo], pero bueno, si necesitas la lógica de cómo funciona, veamos cual es el problema.

Comment: A que te refieres con `El problema es que no sé cómo hacer para " ir cogiendo" palabra a palabra para ir comparándolo.`

Comment: Alex, necesito sacarme una duda antes de contestarte. ¿Cada elemento del vector es una palabra o puede haber muchas palabras y sabes cuando termina una por el "."? No logro entender para que verificas que haya terminado en "."

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente tienes que razonar ¿qué indica final de palabra? En lenguajes occidentales podemos afirmar que el final de una palabra está determinado por un signo de puntuación o un espacio. Puedes ir iterando letra por letra y cuando llegues a uno de los siguientes caracteres `,` `.` `:` `!` `?`  (espacio) puedes obtener la palabra y compararla con la primera del vector `j`. 
Luego si empiezas por una letra después de esta interrupción quiere decir que estás en una nueva palabra y así sucesivamente.